# firebase.storage(app) arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I get the following error while trying to upload a file to a bucket using @react-native-firebase/storage.

> firebase.storage(app) arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined.

I have the following code (simplified):

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

const upload = () => {
  const ref = storage().ref('black-t-shirt.png');
  ref.putFile(filePath).then(() => {
    console.log('uploaded');
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error', error);
  });
};
```

**Environment:**

- iPhone 11, iOS 13.6
- React Native 0.63.0
- React 16.13.1

I followed the installation instructions as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#3-ios-setup). I also added the `[FIRApp configure];` to /ios/{projectName}/appDelegate.m. I've added a GoogleService-Info.plist to the ios folder as described. Basically I followed all the instructions like described here.

My question is: is this a bug, or do I have to initialize a firebase app (like the error says) as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/app/usage#initializing-secondary-apps)?

Comment: Do you have @react-native-firebase/app in your package.json?

Comment: yes it is in my package.json.